# using jquery.InArray() if i have a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

in my javascript, i have an Array of **Calendar** objects.

Each **Calendar** objects has an array of **CalendarEvent** objects

Each **CalendarEvent** object has a property **Date, Name**.

i want to check, give a date, it its exists in a specific Calendar.

I wanted to see if i could use jquery.InArray() but it seems like i have to loop through every **CalendarEvent** object in the **Calendar** to find it.

is there any faster way to do this search ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any faster way to do this search ??

You can build an index (e.g. a reverse lookup).

For example, your Calendar object could have an object of Date => CalendarEvent mappings.  The key (the Date) must be serialized to a string (to be inserted into the object), so you may want to use the UNIX time as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure you've outlined, the only way to detect whether a particular date exists is to loop through the array of Calender objects and then to subsequently loop through its events. As strager has mentioned, you could maintain an object mapping each date to a specific index or CalenderEvent, but this would presumably require modification of the Calender logic.